# My WordPress CSS stopped working overnight

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Last night and this morning, my WordPress website was working fine. Until earlier on, my CSS stopped working properly.

When you hover over some menu a nested under some `<li>`, a hover effect with a transition is supposed to happen. That stopped working, my owl carousel when the page load doesn't show up until the scroll function gets activated.

I am suspecting that its a problem with my cache, but I tried using Stackpath CDN to solve that and it didn't change anything. I am truly lost as to what to do.

On the customize menu, the controls for the hover colors don't work for the menu links either

This is my website: stylehercloset.co.uk

And this is my JavaScript file:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  // owl caroussel
  jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

  items:1,
  navRewind:true,
  center:true,
  autoplay:true,
  autoplayTimeout:3000
  });

  /* end of owl caroussel */
  // adobe typekit
  try{
    Typekit.load({ async: true });
  }
  catch(e){}

  // end of typekit

   jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

  if(window.pageYOffset > 394){
   jQuery("#access").css({"position":"fixed", 
    "z-index":"2",
    "left":"0px",
    "top":"0px",
    "border":"0px",
    "border-width":"1px",
    "border-bottom-style":"solid",
    "margin-top":"auto"

    /*"padding-top":"2.5em" */});
 }

   if(window.pageYOffset < 394){

   jQuery("#access").css({"position":"initial",
    "padding":"0px",
    "border-top":"1px",
    "border-bottom":"1px",
    "border-top-style":"solid",
    "border-bottom-style":"solid",
    "margin-top":"0.5em"
  });
 } 

  }); // end of scroll function


  // code for the footer area

jQuery("#first,#second,#third,#fourth").addClass("col-xs col-sm-1 col-md-3 col-3");


jQuery("#footer-widget-area").addClass("row");


jQuery("#primary, #secondary").addClass("col-xs col-sm-3"); 

  jQuery(".small-nav i").click(function(){
   jQuery("div.menu").slideToggle("slow");

  });
});
```

And this is the relevant CSS from my style.css:

```
  #access .menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #40E0D0 !important; }
```

and this is from my functions.php file

```
function customizer_css(){

   ?>

   <style type="text/css">

   *h1 {
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('h1_font'); ?>;
   }

   * h2 {
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('h2_font'); ?>;
   }

    *h3 {
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('h3_font'); ?>;
   }

    *h4 {
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('h4_font'); ?>;
   }

   *h5 {
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('h5_font'); ?>;
   }

  * p {
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('p_font'); ?>;
   }

   *a {
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('a_font'); ?>;
   }

    #site-title {
        <?php echo get_theme_mod('title_position'); ?>
        font-size:<?php echo get_theme_mod('title_size'); ?>em !important;
    }

   #primary a, #secondary a {
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('widget_a_font'); ?>;
   }

   #small-menu, #access, #wrapper,#footer #colophon{
        background-color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('website_colour') ?> !important; 
   }

    #header-bg {
    background-image: url('<?php echo get_header_image(); ?>');
    background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('header_colour'); ?> ;
    background-position: <?php echo get_theme_mod('header_bg_position_x_lg','0%'); ?> 
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('header_bg_position_y_lg','0%'); ?> !important;
   } 

    #main a, #footer-widget-area a {
      color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('link_colour'); ?> !important ;
      }

    .current_page_item a, #access .menu ul a:hover {
        background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('hover_colour'); ?> !important ;
    }

    #access .el:hover {
        color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('hover_colour'); ?> !important ;
    }

    h1#site-title a{
        <?php echo get_theme_mod('title_font_style'); ?>;
    } 

   @media screen and (max-width:767px) {

    #header-bg {

    background-position: <?php echo get_theme_mod('header_bg_position_x_xs','0%'); ?> 
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('header_bg_position_y_xs','0%'); ?> !important;

   }

        #site-title {
        <?php echo get_theme_mod('title_position_xs'); ?>
        font-size:<?php echo get_theme_mod('title_size_xs'); ?>em !important;
    } 


   } /* end of mobile size */

   @media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){

        #header-bg {
     background-position: <?php echo get_theme_mod('header_bg_position_x_sm','0%'); ?> 
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('header_bg_position_y_sm','0%'); ?> !important;
   }

    #site-title {
        <?php echo get_theme_mod('title_position_sm'); ?>
        font-size:<?php echo get_theme_mod('title_size_sm'); ?>em !important;
    }

   } /* end of small*/

   @media screen and (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){

        #header-bg {
        background-position: <?php echo get_theme_mod('header_bg_position_x_md','0%'); ?> 
    <?php echo get_theme_mod('header_bg_position_y_md','0%'); ?> !important;

   }

     #site-title {
        <?php echo get_theme_mod('title_position_md'); ?>
        font-size:<?php echo get_theme_mod('title_size_md'); ?>em !important;
    }


   }  // end of medium
   </style>

 <?php
}


//add actions

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','style_n_scripts');

//theme customizer api
add_action( 'customize_register', 'customizer_api' );

//theme support

add_action('init', 'shc_theme_support');

// theme customizer css

add_action( 'wp_head', 'customizer_css');
```

Comment: Might want to check source code for possible html errors and even firebug or something else to see if you have javascript errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a CSS issues/conflict. When you remove the `float:left;` on the element with id `#access` on line 386 of your stylesheet it gets fixed and your carousel appears.

Or add the class `clearfix` to the element with id `#header`.

Read more about [clearfix](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html)

Answer (score 0):

In style.css line: 386 remove the `float`. `#access { float:none; }`